# Use SQL functions in QGIS layer filter

Tags: qgis, qgis-expression

I have a layer that contains dates stored in field `timedate` as strings, with different format e.g.

```
2022-05-13T15:37:05.260
Thu Mar 28 15:07:35 2019
```

(because they are inherited from the compilation of various data sources, but never mind)

The layer is part of a geopackage, if this is relevant, and I'm under 3.30.

I would like to display only the items from 2022.

I can build the following SQL query that (hoping there are not too many edge cases) will return the year only:

```
try(
    to_int(right(trim("timedate"),4)),
    to_int(left(trim("timedate"),4))
   )
```

1. I tried to use the above expression as a "provider layer filter", e.g. using the query builder:

   try(to_int(right(trim("timedate"),4)),
   to_int(left(trim("timedate"),4))) = '2022'

This fails with

> An error occurred when executing the query, please check the expression syntax.

2. I used this expression to build a virtual field `year`.
   However, this field does not show in the query builder, and can of course not be used in the query builder.

I understand that the filter builder only use a limited subset of SQL (unlike the expression window), but... how can I filter the layer?

Comment: For the field to appear in the query builder it need to be a "real" field (not virtual). If adding a field to your table is an option this is the way to go

Comment: The best way to handle timestamp data is to store it in a datetime field.  This gives you the ability to format time-based queries in a standard SQL query. I strongly suggest you add a new column, then run one pass through the text to conditionally cast it, depending on the format string that works.

Comment: yes I do realize that my later is poorly conformed and does not follow good practice but ... this is what I have to deal with ! Calculating a new, sanitized field may work, but I'm a bit reluctant as I would have to do it with each new data import or update (I cannot fully guarantee that my data will be clean). Still, maybe the best option, considering. Thanks.